# Adding specific characters in specific positions within a string in Java

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite

I am storing date values within a SQLite database in the format 20121224 (so that I can easily sort the database by date) my question is how can I get the date from the format "20121224" to "2012/12/24" after being extracted from the database using java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test003 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        String s = "20121224";
        Date dt = sdf1.parse(s);
        System.out.println(sdf2.format(dt));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd";

private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new
   SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

public static long dateAsLong(Calendar cal){
   return Long.parseLong(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
}

public static Calendar dateAsCalendar(long l){
   try {
                 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                 c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(String.valueOf(l)));
                 return c;

          } catch (ParseException e) {
                 return null;
          }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `String`s are immutable, so you can't modify the `String` you get back from the database; you have to make a new one. Easiest way, if your dates are guaranteed to be in yyyyMMdd format (ie, you don't store January as "01"), and you just want another `String` to come out the other end:

```
StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder();
date.append(dateStr.substring(0,4));
date.append("/");
date.append(dateStr.substring(4,6));
date.append("/");
date.append(dateStr.substring(6,8));
// use date.toString() wherever you need it
```

**However**, I'd recommend looking into [how SQLite recommends you store dates](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). These are common formats and will allow you to use Java's built-in `Date` and `DateFormat` class in more conventional and convenient ways.

I see someone else has beaten me to submitting an answer while I was typing this...that suggestion will work, but it has you constructing 2 `SimpleDateFormat` objects, which isn't necessarily the most efficient way to go. Depends on how often you're doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strftime` function

Syntax:

```
strftime(timestring, modifiers...)
```

This returns the date formatted according to the format string specified

```
Example:

    SELECT strftime('%d-%m-%Y') from TABLE_NAME;

Output:

24-11-2013
```

You can find all the formatters [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_date_time.htm)